# Interpreting an outcrop of a thick pure silica bed in a volcanic setting

Tags: volcanology, pyroclastic-flows

How can a nearly pure silica bed with 250 m x 50 m x 1.5 m dimensions be interpreted in a volcanic/pyroclastic setting? Here is a photo of it.[image]

Comment: My guess is that this rock is showing evidence of hydro-thermal alteration after the pyroclastic deposit was formed when heated groundwater / magmatic fluids flowed through the rock.

Comment: What's the stuff above and below the chert?

Comment: I didn't observed contacting rocks. Note the blocky texture/structure and vesiculates/hollows/holes. The vesicules may transmit thermal waters.

Comment: Gary, what are the evidences of the rock made you think that it was hydro-thermally altered? What is the degree of the alteration (regarding severity/intensity)?